# Python Selenium only gives me 5 results for this website

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to scrape the website by selenium but my code only gives me 5-8 results out of all.
Pls help

My results:

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
         
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
     
chrome = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
chrome.get("https://www.midland.com.hk/en/list/buy/%E6%90%9C%E5%B0%8B-H-f4076dba")
time.sleep(10)    


chrome.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

time.sleep(5)
elements = chrome.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(),"Tsuen King Garden")]')
time.sleep(3)

for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Comment: Add more details, what do you want which elements, add site url or HTML, explain so someone can hepl you.

Comment: I attached my results and my code cannot scrape the whole page.

Comment: Use `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` to scroll down and put inside a loop every 5 items it scrolls down or every element.